# Discerning arguments of verbs, predicates?

Tags: predicate

I think I get that a verb may utilize arguments. Does a predicate announce something of an object (or subject)?

In,

> "**The lake** froze **solid**".

*The lake* seems a noun phrase that *solid* may predicate on?

Comment: I think you're really getting this! Yes; *solid* is a 'secondary predicate', which is a sort of optional complement to the verb, and it is 'predicated of' (attributed to) the subject, *The lake*. Freezing caused the lake to become solid. When intransitive verbs like *freeze* take these secondary complements they are almost always predicated of the subject; when a transitive verb takes a secondary complement it is almost always predicated of the object.

Comment: @StoneyB: Are "secondary predicate" and "secondary complement" synonymous, or is one of them a typo?

Comment: @ruakh It's a 'predicate' with respect to the subject, a 'complement' with respect to the verb.

Comment: @StoneyB: Yes, but what makes it a "secondary complement"? (I assume it's a "secondary predicate" because the "primary predicate" is *froze*? But what's the primary complement?)

Comment: @ruakh *Freeze* is intransitive -- it forms a complete predicate by itself -- so it has no complement. The term 'secondary complement' indicates that *solid* in this construction acts as if it were a complement; it's presence is 'licensed' by the verb/predicator and it is effected by the action of the verb, but it's not a true complement in the sense of being a necessary argument of the verb. It's just one of the quirks of English.

Comment: @StoneyB I think you've got a pretty good answer spread among your comments. I considered compiling it as an answer, but you clearly have a much better grasp of grammatical vocabulary than I do, so maybe you'd like to do it? This question is pretty high on the 'unanswered' list

Comment: @StoneyB, I concur with DCShannon. Please compile it into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In traditional grammar a sentence comprises of **a subject** and **a predicate**.

> - **The lake** *froze solid*. [**Subject** => *The lake* **Predicate** => *froze solid*]
> - **I** *am no one special*. [**Subject** => *I* **Predicate** => *am no one special*]
> - **The sky** *is blue*. [**Subject** => *The sky* **Predicate** => *is blue*]

In the sentences above **"The lake", "I"** and **"the sky"** are the subjects and **"froze solid", "am no one special"** and **"is blue"** are the predicates.

However modern linguists use the word - **predicate** - in a different way. They call the verb and it's accompanying auxiliary or modal verbs a predicate.

> - The lake **froze** solid. [**Predicate** => *froze*]
> - I **am** no one special. [**Predicate** => *am*]
> - The sky **is** blue. [**Predicate** => *is*]

In the sentences above **"froze"**, **"am"** and **"is"** are predicates.

An argument is an expression that help complete the meaning of a predicate. A predicate can take one, two or three arguments.

> - The lake **froze** solid. [**Predicate** => *froze* **Argument** => *the lake* and *solid*]
> - The lake froze. [**predicate** => *froze* **Argument** => *the lake*]
> - I **am** no one special. [**Predicate** => *am* **Argument** => *I* and *no one special* (NP -> *no one* Adj -> *special*]
> - The sky **is** blue. [**Predicate** => *is* **Argument** => *the sky* and *blue*]

Different verb can take different arguments.

We have already seen the verb - **froze** - can take either one argument (*the lake*) or two arguments (*The lake* and *solid*).

> - *The lake* **froze** *solid*.

In the sentence the verb - **froze** - takes two arguments - **the lake** and **solid**. The word - **solid** - is also a complement. To be precise it's called subject complement. It's also called predicate on the subject.

> - *David* **punched** *Sam* *unconscious*. [**Predicate** => *punch* **Argument** => *David*, *Sam* and *unconscious*]

In the sentence above, the word - **unconscious** - is actually a complement, an object complement.

So in some cases the concept of an argument and a complement overlaps, but in some cases they do not.

**For example -**

> - *Jim* **gave** *Sam* *a beautiful present*. [**Predicate** => *gave* **Argument** => *Jim*, *Sam* and *a beautiful present(NP)*]
> - *Jim* **gave** *a beautiful present* *to Sam*. [**Predicate** => *gave* **Argument** => *Jim*, *a beautiful present(NP)* and *to Sam(PP)*]

In the last sentence above, it's clear that the predicate - **gave** - takes a noun, a noun phrase (NP) and a prepositional phrase (PP) as its arguments.

*to Sam* is a prepositional phrase, where *to* is a preposition, and *Sam* is the complement of the preposition -*to*. So here the complement and argument are different entity.

---

According to the *theta-theory*, the verb - **freeze** - can either take one argument or two arguments.

*freeze* - *(verb)* - Argument( 1. NP)

Or

*freeze* - *(verb)* - Argument( 1. NP 2. AdjP)

And so both of the following sentences are correct -

> The lake froze.
>
> The lake froze solid.

**For further reading on complement, predicate and argument -**

1. [Complement - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_%28linguistics%29)
2. [Predicate - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_%28grammar%29)
3. [Argument - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_%28linguistics%29)

Answer (score 0):

By mixing grammar terms of various modern grammar schools with traditional grammar terms and using a traditional term with a new and totally different meaning you get a salad, but never a clear understanding of the language system. My recommendation: Try to learn the traditional grammar terms  and make amendments if they are not clear enough for you.