# syntax of postpositioned adjectivals

Tags: adjectives, participles, supplementation, secondary-predicates

In

> "No Chinese emperor was more resplendently arrayed. As for the cigarette that he holds out, **half smoked**, to be taken and deposited by his valet, a whole civilization--urbane, authoritative, preposterous, and doomed--resides in that single gesture."

It is difficult for me to discern what is what. What is the grammatical function of *half smoked*? Is it an adjective (adjectival[?]) phrase placing information on a noun, *cigarette*?

> "No Chinese emperor was more resplendently arrayed. **As for the cigarette that he holds out**, half smoked, **to be taken and deposited by his valet**, a whole civilization--urbane, authoritative, preposterous, and doomed--resides in that single gesture."

*As for the cigarette that he holds out(,[?]) to be taken and deposited by his valet*, what is the grammatical function of this? Is it a dependent phrase?

> "No Chinese emperor was more resplendently arrayed. As for the cigarette that he holds out, half smoked, to be taken and deposited by his valet, a whole civilization--**urbane, authoritative, preposterous, and doomed**--resides in that single gesture."

Is this an adjectival apposition?

I am guessing that *a whole civilization resides in that single gesture* is the  main clause here? or is it a dependent clause?

Comment: You are definitely coming to understand this! I have edited your question to remove the unidiomatic use of *may seem* where only a simple copula is required. There is no need of either *may* or *seem* to indicate your uncertainty, because the very fact that you are asking questions does that!

Answer (score 3):

Two of these are fairly common literary devices which you are unlikely to encounter in speech.

- *Half-smoked* is, as you guess, an adjectival phrase modifying cigarette. (I call it "an adjectival phrase" rather than an "adjective phrase" because *smoked* is not a full adjective but retains its verbal sense as well: *half-smoked* is equivalent to *which had only been half smoked*.)

  In the position it occupies, however, the phrase is not an attributive adjectival but a secondary complement, like *solid* in your [previous question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/57365/32). And it is not a resultative complement like *solid* in *froze* solid--a result of the action of the verb; it is merely a description of the cigarette. The fact that it is bracketed with commas also indicates that it is not "integrated" into the main clause, as a resultative complement is, but something added to the sense of the main clause: a *supplement*.
- *urbane, authoritative, &c* is a chain of conjoined adjectives modifying *gesture*. It is, as you suggest, set in apposition to the noun; like the earlier adjectival it is a supplement, even more strongly marked in this case with dashes.

*To be taken &c*, on the other hand, is integrated into the sentence. Note that it is not set off with a comma: the comma before it belongs to the pair which bracket the supplement. This sort of infinitive phrase modifies the predicate as an adverbial of purpose telling why the smoker held the cigarette out: so that the valet would dispose of it.

You are correct in taking "a whole civilization resides in that single gesture" to be the main clause. *As for the cigarette* with all its following modifiers is just a preposition phrase marking a new topic in the discourse, and preparing the reader by signalling what the main clause will be talking about.

Comment: Why may it get placed *half smoked* not half-smoked as an adjective? *As for the cigarette that he holds out, half smoked, to be taken and deposited by his valet, a whole civilization--urbane, authoritative, preposterous, and doomed--resides in that single gesture."* So may I discern it *As for the cigarette that he holds out*, a phrase, *the cigarette that he holds out* may get me. There seems maybe a noun phrase *the cigarette* and maybe another noun *he*, *holds* maybe a transitive verb. I may not get it. May *He holds out.* seem a complete sentence?

Comment: @saySay *that he holds out* is a relative clause (*he* is its  subject and *that* 'stands for' both *the cigarette* and the 'missing* object of *holds out*), so it cannot be an independent clause. . . .

Comment: So *the cigarette* noun (noun phrase[?]), *that he holds out* a relative clause? Maybe it seems like passive voice, *He holds* incomplete sentence, maybe *holds* seems transitive, maybe requesting an object, and maybe He holds X out, (no object of *holds*). Maybe it may go *He holds **that*** out. And here, it may seem passive? *That he holds out*? Maybe like *The chair, **that he holds out**, seems new?* I may aim to maybe go get some information upon "relative clauses".

Comment: I may not get a grammatical function of *As for* in this.

Comment: *to be taken and deposited by his valet* maybe a different phrase, maybe infinitive? an adverbial infinitive? subject *valet*, there may seem maybe three verbs, *be*, *taken* and maybe *deposited*, or maybe a verb phrase *to be taken*, and another verb, *deposited*? What may I discern a verb here that gets an argument, subject, valet? May you write ***To be taken and deposited by his valet**, the cigarette got held out*?

Comment: @saSay The infinitive passive auxiliary *be* operates over conjunct participles; bracket it like this: [to be [taken and deposited]].  The subject of the construction (and Patient of *take* and *deposit*) is *the cigarette*. Your paraphrase would be acceptable if the clause were independent.

Comment: So *to be*, and *taken and deposited by his valet* two phrases? I may not get conjunct principles. So they request an object? I guess you may place two verbs that request (maybe one[?]) argument, *cigarette(?)*. I guess I didn’t think there may go two verbs like that, (and this may seem passive so cigarette goes where a subject may go?) I may not get *to be* in a phrase (maybe it may not seem a phrase, mostly two words, an auxiliary?). I may get *taken and deposited by his valet* may seem a participle phrase?

Comment: I may not get why we may not get to write ***To be taken and deposited by his valet**, the cigarette got held out.* May you maybe write this? *The cigarette, (object in subject place[?] passive?) **to be taken and deposited by his valet**, got held out?* I thank you, StoneyB.